# Xml element deletion using style sheet

Tags: xml, xslt, stylesheet

I need to delete certain elements from xml using xsl , is there anyway by using style sheet we can delete records from xml ?
I tried some examples given on the site but not able to delete the records from xml.
If it is not possible then could we generate new xml file after applying style sheet on the xml ?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you have to copy everything you want to keep, and don't copy what you want to delete.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
<!-- copy what you want -->
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
<!-- this will override the previous copy, and since it's an empty, will delete it (replace match with an appropriate condition)-->
    <xsl:template match="expression pointing to elements deleted"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

More informations : http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#copying

Answer (score 0):

> is there anyway by using style sheet we can delete records from xml ?

An XSL transformation will **not** modify the original XML document.

> If it is not possible then could we generate new xml file after
>   applying style sheet on the xml ?

Yes, that is the usual course of action. How are you initiating the XSL transformation?